# How apt-get know how to download ElasticSearch?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, apt, apt-get, package-managers

I'm following the [instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html#deb-repo) to install Elasticsearch from `apt-get` and I'd like to know how it is actually working.

1. I've added a file `elastic-7.x.list` in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the following content:

```
deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I guess the apt-get uses the entry in the `elastic-7.x.list` file to get information about `packages` in this remote repository.

But when I go to  https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt I get a `Not Found` from my browser.

When I do this with a link with a ubuntu default repository (e.g http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) I can see the directories:
[image]

I've found the http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu link in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

How the `apt-get` actually works to get information from the link `https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt`?

Comment: Were you able to install the elasticsearch, even it says url not found?

Comment: @Opster ES Ninka Yes, I installed without any problem. Actually, this is more like a question "why did it work", haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apt repository can be browsable, but it doesn't have to be. The Elastic one isn't — IMO because it doesn't generate the index files. Those aren't needed by apt since it can pick up the right resources without the index files in between.

If you want a browsable catalog, use https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases.

Comment: what do you mean by index files and why it's not required by apt in this case, could you point of some reference material which can give us information in detail.

Comment: apt knows where to find its metadata — for example https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages. We don't generate index.html files for the folders since apt can automatically navigate them. But that makes the repository non browsable.